# How to connect to TFS Server using libgit2?

Tags: git, tfs, libgit2

I know `git-credential-manager.exe` is used to connect to TFS server, so, I want to use `git-credential-manager.exe` to connect to TFS server using libgit2.  How would I do this?

Comment: Is their no documentation from TFS or libgit2 to help?

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely,I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: If you want to use `git-credential-manager`, you'll need to use it yourself.  Here's an example using LibGit2Sharp:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010941/libgit2sharp-and-authentication-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, I use the command line to pop up the login box. The command line is as follows:

1, git.exe credential-manager fill

2, host=**personal.visualstudio.com**

3, protocol=**https**

Next I use **CreateProcess** in C++, but to write the command line through the pipeline to Process, it is a bit difficult to implement, I have other things are busy, wait until after enough time to complete it